# Add a hover color in html and css for span?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I got a problem for hovering color in span classes. I was able to make two classes in this page, but in another classes **a hover** not effected. In this case, I just included into my test page, Please check it out, and let me know what is the wrong inside of my code ? Really i got confused, and I don't know how to solve it.

Please check this following like:

> http://www.malayatourism.com/thisistest/testnowjobdoneperfectlyworkjobdone/index.php

As you can see, there are 7 subjects, just **Main** , **Time** and **Gallery** already effected to hover color, and another subjects not effected, however these subjects already effected by **slides2.css"**, I mean, positions and colors, sizes, everything is ok, but just ***A HOVERING COLOR is not working***

Can you please check it and if its possible tell me what is the wrong inside?

*For your information , I have to use just SPAN, I can't use DIV OR SOMETHING ELSE.*

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Please post the minimum code required to reproduce the problem *here* (use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18814153/edit) to edit it into your question).

Comment: I don't know where is exactly problem , If I knew, I could send minimum code, that's why I'm asking you to check it, cause everything is working, just hovering color is not working..

Comment: Your markup has some mistakes in it. At least one `<span>` tag has a "style" attribute that should instead be a "class" attribute.

Comment: Trying to isolate the problem is the first step in debugging code. Try it (you can use http://jsfiddle.net), and maybe you'll find the answer yourself.

Comment: @Amin: "For your information, I have to use just SPAN, I can't use DIV OR SOMETHING ELSE." **FYI - then your code is invalid!** Sorry, but rarely read such nonsense. See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#paragraph and http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#phrasing-content

Comment: thnx buddy, I have to change this code, however with span is working well, and there is no issue, just hovering color has problem, but anyhow I have to change it and I use DIV instead of span, maybe it will be done.. thnx for your attention and post..

Answer (score 1):

You really just need to use your browser's stylesheet inspection tools to debug that stuff.  For example, the "Gallery" link doesn't respond to hover because the markup and the CSS rules simply don't coincide.  The markup looks like this:

```
<span class="l">
  <a style="galleryscaptionsmall" href="http://gallery.com/">
    <span class="circleContainer">
      <span class="vAligner">
        <p class="inner">
          <span class="importantValue">
            <span class="number"></span>
            <span class="galleryscaptionsmall">Gallery</span>
          </span>
        </p>
      </span>
  </a>
</span>
```

That `<a>` tag with "style" set to "galleryscaptionsmall" is clearly wrong; that should be a "class" attribute.  There's a style rule for

```
.gallerycaptionsmall a:hover
```

but none of that markup matches that selector. Even if it did, the rule makes the color blue, and that text is *already* blue.

Comment: There is this class in style2.css even text color will effect but not hovering color.. I checked all these ways... Thats why I submitted this question

Comment: @Amin the markup does not match that selector.  That selector matches an `<a>` tag **inside** another tag with that class, but your HTML does not look like that.

Answer (score 1):

Like Admin said in comment, your markup does not match your selector.

Example:
You have this span having class contactcaptionsmall

```
<span class="number contactcaptionsmall">Contact </span>
```

You also have this css for hovering

```
.contactcaptionsmall a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
```

This line will only match if you have a `<a>` inside an element having class contactcaptionsmall.

Exactly what you have done with your time element

```
<span class="timecaptionsmall"><a href="http://time.com/">Time</a></span>
```

There is a `<a>` element inside a span having class timecaptionsmall that fit with this css

```
.timecaptionsmall a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: yellow;}
```

You have 2 choices, have this your stylesheet

```
.contactcaptionsmall:hover {color: black;}
```

Or change your span for this

```
<span class="number contactcaptionsmall"><a href="your link here">Contact</a></span>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOO MUCH, PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED... I used your trick, especially class="number contactcaptionsmall" and also I added <p inner> inside .. now hovering color is working well.. Thank you soooooo much... Thank you, Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('.maincaptionsmall').wrapInner('<a href="http://main.com/" style="maincaptionsmall"></a>');
        $('.timecaptionsmall').wrapInner('<a href="http://time.com/" style="timecaptionsmall"></a>');
        $('.l').wrapInner('<a href="http://gallery.com/" style="galleryscaptionsmall"></a>');
        $('.r').wrapInner('<a href="http://patient.com/" style="patientscaptionsmall"></a>');
        $('.cost').wrapInner('<a href="http://contact.com/" style="contactcaptionsmall"></a>');
        $('.lowerBound').wrapInner('<a href="http://address.com/" style="addresscaptionsmall"></a>');
        $('.conclusion').wrapInner('<a href="http://services.com/" style="servicescaptionsmall"></a>');
    });        
    </script>
```

Your first two lines adds anchor tag within the span containing the text. But the other lines add anchor tag to the parent container(See how you have to click on the text in the time and main bubbles for redirect but you can click anywhere on the bubble for others for redirect).
your styles

```
.timecaptionsmall a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: yellow;}
```

look for anchor tag inside of the span of the text.
When this is adhered, your hover works(which is the first two cases).  For the other cases, since there is no anchor tag on the inside of the span containing the text, your hover does not work.

Comment: Thanks buddy, problem has been solved, the issue was comming from class="number contactcaptionsmall" and also <p> now, its done :-) thanks for your time and attention..